# MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0 not initializing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an application which is using  MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0 component.
I am using below code in javascript to initialize this component in my web application.

DefaultPage.aspx is like:

```
var objXml = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0");
```

My web application is pointing to TestApp virtual directory, and below is my complete URL

```
http://localhost/TestApp/DefaultPage.aspx
```

When I browse the above URL from IIS 7.5, using content View -> Browse

Msxml is loading properly.

But if open some IE Browser instance and paste the above URL, it is throwing below error.

> Error: Automation server can't create object

Please suggest.

Comment: It's recommended to use version 6 falling back to 3 ['Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0', 'Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0']

Comment: First result on Google for "Automation server can't create object" has a potential solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8db7ec28-45ca-4859-b051-f0571a4da14e/error-automation-server-cant-create-object?forum=ieitpropriorver#bb10c2f2-5f7f-4d66-b851-4a33f64eb4f1

Answer (score 0):

Its look like that , if we run IE in Administrator mode, working fine.

Comment: I would not rely on version 4, I have win7 filled with SDKs/MS Dev tools and I don't have it. v6/3 will not present these problems